# How to show custom control as a drop down window?

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, toolstripdropdown, toolstripcontrolhost

I want to show my custom control(eg: `monthcalendar`) as a drop-down (popup) window.
One option is to use `ToolStripDropDown` and `ToolStripControlHost` as the second example in [msdn example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown(v=vs.110).aspx).

My doubt is:

1. `ToolStripDropDown` should be used for `ToolStrip` items - is this correct or not?
2. Any other better options to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Is it recommended to use ToolStripDropDown for controls other than the ToolStrip items ?

Comment: Basically ToolStripDropDown suits my requirement. But my doubt is, is it a good or suggested way to show custom control as a drop down window.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple control, it should be completely fine to use the ToolStripDropDown/ToolStripControlHost combination. More complex controls, however, have sizing, focus, and tab order issues that are difficult to correct. I would recommend that if your custom control has more than one "edit" type child control in it, you're probably better off creating a custom dialog and not trying to make it work in a dropdown.